# how to know when chat coversations have been deleted

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-messenger

How to see full conversations on chat. And how to tell if chats have been deleted?

I looked on Facebook saw an alert. But maybe the chat was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to see if chats were deleted, unless someone saved the page before the fact.

But there is a way to see if the message was [read](https://www.facebook.com/messages?action=recent-messages), [archived](https://www.facebook.com/messages/archived?action=recent-messages) or [classified as spam](https://www.facebook.com/messages/spam?action=recent-messages)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can tell if your conversation messages have been deleted by that person in messenger. Simply go to that person's Facebook page, click on message, if no past conversation is there then they have deleted it end of story. I swear people really don't have a clue about Facebook. We all need to go back to MeetMe.com...!